# XSL Store Value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to store variable from XML input.    I will then use this value to test against another element value.
The XML is generated by IBM Watson Explorer. 
Here's the XML (Updated):

```
<vce>
  <param name="v:project" value="pru-collection"/>
  <param name="query" value="xyz"/>
  <param name="render.function" value="xml-feed-display"/>
  <param name="content-type" value="text/xml"/>
  <list path="" num="23" level="0" start="0" per="25">
    <document url="https://example.net">
      <content name="Avatar_Image" type="text">...</content>
      <content name="keywords" type="text">xyz</content>
      <content name="owner" type="text">...</content>
    </document>
    <document url="https://example.net">
      <content name="Avatar_Image" type="text">...</content>
      <content name="keywords" type="text">123</content>
      <content name="owner" type="text">...</content>
    </document>
    <document url="https://example.net">
      <content name="Avatar_Image" type="text">...</content>
      <content name="keywords" type="text">abc</content>
      <content name="owner" type="text">...</content>
    </document>
  </list>
</vce>
```

and here is my XSL.  This is a free text XSL stylesheet that is internal to IBM application:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:param name="saveQuery" select="**../param[@name='query']/@value**" />
        <scope>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/scope/*[not(name() = 'document')]" />
            <boost name="df" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </scope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <document url="{@url}">
            <xsl:if test="viv:test(content[@name='keywords'], '$saveQuery', 'case-insensitive-regex')">
               <xsl:attribute name="boost-name">df</xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="boost-display">boost-and-list</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="* | text() | comment()" />
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
```

It looks like `$saveQuery` is not correctly storing the value of the 'query' tag.  For testing purposes, by manually comparing the `content[@name='keywords'` with actual value `xyz` instead of `$saveQuery`, it works fine.

Updated Code

```
<xsl:template match="/vce">
<scope>
  <xsl:copy-of select="/scope/*[not(name() = 'document')]" />
  <boost name="df" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:with-param name="saveQuery" select="param[@name='query']/@value" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</scope>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:param name="saveQuery" />
  <xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:with-param name="saveQuery" select="$saveQuery" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="document">
  <xsl:param name="saveQuery" />
  <document url="{@url}">
    <xsl:if test="viv:test(content[@name='keywords'], '$saveQuery', 'case-insensitive-regex')">
      <xsl:attribute name="boost-name">df</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="boost-display">boost-and-list</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="* | text() | comment()" />
  </document>
</xsl:template>
```

Updated 2.0
This code works fine in xsltransform tool but not on the IBM environment.  Any idea folks why the value is still not being passed to saveQuery?  Or maybe idea about different approach?

```
<xsl:template match="/vce">
  <scope>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="list/document">
    <xsl:with-param name="saveQuery" select="'xyz'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </scope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document">
  <!-- for chk this line works -->
  <!-- <xsl:param name="saveQuery" select="'xyz'"/>-->
   <xsl:param name="saveQuery" />
   <document>
      <xsl:if test="content[@name='keywords'] = $saveQuery">
         <xsl:attribute name="boost-name">df</xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="boost-display">boost-and-list</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="* | text() | comment()" />
   </document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes. Your observation is right: The param/variable `$saveQuery` is in another scope, so the second template cannot access it. Apart from that, you're not even using it in a `<call-template>`. This is not a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks zx485.  I have modified my XML to look closer to actual case.

Comment: There is no `scope` element in your XML - so `<xsl:copy-of select="/scope/*[not(name() = 'document')]" />` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To do this kind of thing, you need to pass the parameters from one template to another. In the calling template:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document">
  <xsl:with-param name="saveQuery" select="./query"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

In the called template:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
  <xsl:param name="query"/>
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Variables in XSLT have *static scope* - when you refer to a variable or parameter using `$var`, the variable `var` must be declared either in a global declaration, or earlier in the same template or function.

Answer (score 0):

Your first template matches, because any well-formed XML input has a root, so `/` always matches.  However:

1. In best practice, `xsl:param` is used to bind input parameters, not to define internal variables.
2. There is no `query` element anywhere in your input XML, let alone at the start of the file, so the `select="/query"` statement results in an empty set.
3. Your `scope` code is likewise connected to nothing in your input XML.

<s>Your second template will never match, because your input XML has no `document` element.  It thus follows that there is also no `url` attribute for this missing `document` element.</s>

#### Update

With your recent edit to expand what we see of your input XML, `document` in your second template could now match.  However, your first template matches on `/` (the logical root), and applying templates from there will only pass along anything at the top level -- in your case, the `vce` element.  Since `vce` has no matching template, none of the `vce` children have templates applied, and since `document` is a grandchild of `vce`, that template will never match.

`scope` and `query` are still nowhere to be found, so these portions of your first template will continue to fail.

Comment: Thanks Eirikr.  I think I should be using xsl:variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/vce">
    <scope>
        <!-- some content here -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list/document">
            <xsl:with-param name="saveQuery" select="param[@name='query']/@value"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </scope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:param name="saveQuery"/>
    <document>
        <!-- use the parameter here -->
    </document>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the `xsl:apply-templates` explicitly selects the target `document` elements, so the parameter value is passed directly to the matching template. Without this, you would have to add your own template to replace the built-in template that ensures recursion, and make it carry the parameter as it traverses the tree:

```
<xsl:template match="/vce">
    <scope>
        <!-- some content here -->
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="saveQuery" select="param[@name='query']/@value"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </scope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="saveQuery"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="saveQuery" select="$saveQuery"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:param name="saveQuery"/>
    <document>
        <!-- use the parameter here -->
    </document>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added:

Apparently your processor is non-conforming. You may try accessing the node directly from the target template, e.g. something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/vce">
    <scope>
        <!-- some content here -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list/document"/>
    </scope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:variable name="saveQuery" select="/vce/param[@name='query']/@value"/>
    <document>
        <!-- use the variable here -->
    </document>
</xsl:template>
```

Or even more directly as:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <document>
        <xsl:if test="content[@name='keywords']=/vce/param[@name='query']/@value">
            <xsl:attribute name="boost-name">df</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="boost-display">boost-and-list</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
    </document>
</xsl:template>
```

But with a non-conforming processor it's a pure guess what might work or not.

Comment: That's right @michael.hor257k.  I want to use this $saveQuery on my if clause.  However, after trying and varying both options above, it didn't address my issue.  That helps me a lot though in slowly understanding XSL concept.  Do you think there's something wrong with the PATH - select="param[@name='query']/@value"/? Can I display the value of the temp variable - saveQuery?

Comment: "*Do you think there's something wrong with the PATH - select="param[@name='query']/@value"/?*" No, provided that your context is `vce` and that the input is what you posted. You can easily test the contents of the passed parameter by including in the output of the target template (or, if your testing environment allows, by using the `xsl:message` instruction).

Comment: That tool is very handy Michael.  Appreciate your help.